# Homepage Routing when using multiple domains per Website

Tags: index.php

I currently run a Magento 2.3.3 multisite installation with the following example of index.php

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
  case 'DOMAIN-A.co.uk':
  case 'www.DOMAIN-A.co.uk':
  case 'DOMAIN-A.com':
  case 'www.DOMAIN-A.com':
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'STORE-A';
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
  break;

  case 'DOMAIN-B.co.uk':
  case 'www.DOMAIN-B.co.uk':
  case 'DOMAIN-B.com':
  case 'www.DOMAIN-B.com':
  case 'DOMAIN-C.uk':
    case 'www.go-diving.co.uk':
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'STORE-B';
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
  break;

  case 'DOMAIN-D.co.uk':
  case 'www.DOMAIN-D.co.uk':
  case 'DOMAIN-D.com':
  case 'www.DOMAIN-D.com':
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'STORE-C';
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
  break;

  default:
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'STORE-D';
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
}
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

I can currently enter DOMAIN-A as either a .co.uk or .com and load any content, with the system redirecting .co.uk or .com to the secure base URL as defined in stores configuration.

DOMAIN-A.co.uk/test
DOMAIN-A.com/test
both return the appropriate page with the slug "test" from the correct website. If DOMAIN-A.com/tes is used, the returned page would be DOMAIN-A.co.uk/test and works as intended, as a page is defined for this URL and store view

If however I enter DOMAIN-A.com, I get an error as no route as been defined for this combination of URL and store view, and I get the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, null given in /home/customer/www/DOMAIN-A.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php:182 Stack trace: #0
```

None of the built-in redirect modules are able to handle redirecting at the domain level, merely the request level.

I'm tempted to try redirecting the absolute URL's in .htaccess, but this seems a bit of a clunky way of solving the problem.

Comment: first of all check all php version of all domains same or not? becuase that error is look like php version error ``Uncaught TypeError: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string,``

Comment: The issue there is that the second parameter is actually returning NULL
If i var_dump the contents of $this->pathConfig->getDefaultPath() it returns NULL on the alternative URL's, and a correct string on the primary URL's. As this is a multisite installation there is only one global PHP version on the hosting panel

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is that the

> vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/AdminPathConfig.php

class has a method called getDefaultPath() that looks for an admin value that doesn't exist.

> return $this->backendConfig->getValue('web/default/admin');

I've tried changing this to cms_home however this results in the alternative url's returning the login page for Magento admin, not the front end page as expected. I'll open a new question explaining the problem in more detail.